# Automate Google App Engine deployment with Google Cloud Build

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment, google-app-engine

I have a Go application wich needs `GCC` during the build process.
The default GAE Go runtimes don't support `GCC`, so I had to configure my `app.yaml` to define the runtime as custom like this:

```
runtime: custom
env: flex

network:
  session_affinity: true

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

Plus, adding a docker file like:

```
FROM golang:latest
RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app/
WORKDIR /app
RUN go build -o main .
CMD ["/app/main"]
```

The problem is that I can't automate the deployment from Cloud Build after Push trigger because GAE deployment doesn't accept having `Dockerfile` and `cloudbuild.yaml` defined together.
At the same time if I added a `cloudbuild.yaml` like:

```
-steps:
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
    args: ["app", "deploy"]
timeout: "1600s"
```

I will be forced to delete the `Dockerfile`!
Is there anyway way to automate the GAE build and deploy with custom runtimes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into the situation you described I could find the relevant public threads on [GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/issues/397) and [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52479595/deploy-to-google-app-engine-flex-environment-from-google-cloud-build-using-docke#answer-54392088).

As an option, try to move the **cloudbuild.yaml** file into a sub-folder to mitigate the issue. Remember to update the Cloud Build trigger to point to the moved file.

Let me know if it helps!